# Options for hanging string lights on patio?

Tags: lighting, patio, landscaping, backyard

I'm wanting to hang string lights to cover my 20x20 patio but struggling with the best option.

I had been planning to use two 8' 4x4 posts secured to 26" half whiskey barrels by retrofit post bases, and then filling the barrels with concrete. My plan was to place these at the far corners of the patio, run steel wire to the posts around the perimeter, and then string the lights from the wire.

However, my concern is that the tension at the top of the posts will be too great, and they'll eventually sag or even tip over. Is that a valid concern?

I know that burying the posts a few feet deep in the ground would be best, but where could I even do that?

[image]

Comment: you can get super lightweight LED string lights, often sold as "fairy lights" that a 4x4 would be super overkill for; they weigh about half a gram per foot. There's also "net lights" that might be simpler to add en masse. Despite being alarmingly cheap, ours have been outside for their third year (all year) are are still going strong. They also use a tiny amount of energy compared to bistro (bulb-based) light strings; 10W is enough for our ~400sqft patio, we still often dim them...

Comment: If you do want the heavy strings, a steel wire can reenforce the posts, like they do for radio towers and tents.

Comment: @dandavis a guy wire can be a trip hazard, though.  Although it looks like the OP has room to drive anchors into the outside corners of the planter area, and there shouldn't be much foot traffic there.